# XCode: "Generating dSYM file" step is repeated on every application run

Tags: xcode

The step is repeated when I stop the application and hit run again, even if no code or other changes have been done to the project. This is frustrating as I'm working on a large codebase and the step takes a long time, killing iteration times.

If anyone has any pointers for where to look to determine why this step is done on every run, it would be appreciated.

Comment: are you "building for testing" or "building for running" or archiving or?  And in your scheme, in the "Test" section, are you testing with the "Release" or "Distribution" version of the app or the "Debug" version of the app?

Comment: I'm building for running, and I'm building and testing the "Debug" version of the app. I'm also running on an actual device (not the simulator), if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this can be turned off?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In your project's Build Settings, under Build Options there's the Debug Information Format fields for debug and release - change the appropriate one from 'DWARF with dSYM file' to just 'DWARF'. This should cut your build times down, however it is removing the file that contains debug symbol information about the build.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed you can launch your app yourself and attach the debugger. This skips that step. My project isn't large enough for this dSYM step to take longer than 2 seconds yet (but I've already noticed it go up to this 2 second mark now that I am linking in a sizable static library).

Furthermore, here on Xcode 4.6.3, I see an option to run without building. In my limited testing it appears to skip all build-related steps.

[image]